# How to get all child element names and values inside a particular element in an XML tag

Tags: c#, .net, regex, xml, xpath

I have a string in the form of a XML with a number of tags :

```
<Code>
<!-- Schema Version MQ Message blocks -->
    <T_C_B>
        < ATXYCB>ABC11</ ATXYCB>
        <BTCWZB>EFG22</BTCWZB>
        < CTATCB>IJK33</CTATCB>
        < DTCAAB>LMN44</DTCAAB>
        <!-- End T_C_B -->
    </T_C_B>

    <D_C_B>
        < ADCB>xs:string</ ADCB>
        < BDCB>xs:string</ BDCB>
        < CDCB>xs:string</ CDCB>
    <!-- End D_ C_B-->
    </D_C_B>
    <U_C_B>
        <UATXYCB>AA2B</ UATXYCB>
        <BUTCWZB>BB4C</BUTCWZB>
        < UCTATCB>C8CD</UCTATCB>
        < DTUCAAB>D9DE</DTUCAAB>
    <!-- End U_C_B->
    </U_C_B>
</Code>
```

I need to find elements inside T_C_B and U_C_B and their values and concatenate with a delimitter like "|" :

> **ATXYCB=ABC11|BTCWZB=EFG22|CTATCB=IJK33|DTCAAB=LMN44|UATXYCB=AA2B|etc……”**

Is there any Regex or Xpath that can be used...?? Or any other workarounds

Comment: Are the comments and spacing exactly the same in your real life input? `<!-- End U_C_B->` is not a valid comment. `</ ATXYCB>` is not a valid tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have such input (with space issues and invalid comments), I suggest 2 ways: XML-based and regex-based (as a fallback).

## XML way

It consists in fixing the issues that prevent parsing with `XElement` and then actual parsing:

```
var xml = "<<YOUR_XML>>";
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"<\s+([\w:-])", "<$1");
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"</\s+([\w:-]+>)", "</$1");
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"(?s)<!--.*?->", string.Empty);
XElement xe = null;
try
{
   xe = XElement.Parse(xml);
   var tags = xe.DescendantsAndSelf()
      .Where(p => p.Name == "T_C_B" || p.Name == "U_C_B")
      .Select(p => new { names = p.Descendants()
                      .Select(m => m.Name.LocalName + "=" + m.Value)
                      .ToList() })
      .ToList();
   var res = string.Empty;
   foreach (var s in tags)
      res += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res) ? "" : "|") +
               string.Join("|", s.names);
}
catch(Exception e) 
{

}
```

## Regex way

You may use the following regex to process your data:

```
<\s*[UT]_C_B\s*>(?:\s*<\s*(?<name>[^<]*)>(?<val>[^<]*)<\s*/\s*\k<name>>.*?)+
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3C%5Cs*%5BUT%5D_C_B%5Cs*%3E(%3F%3A%5Cs*%3C%5Cs*(%3F%3Cname%3E%5B%5E%3C%5D*)%3E(%3F%3Cval%3E%5B%5E%3C%5D*)%3C%5Cs*%2F%5Cs*%5Ck%3Cname%3E%3E.*%3F)%2B&i=%3CCode%3E%0D%0A%3C!--%20Schema%20Version%20MQ%20Message%20blocks%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT_C_B%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%20ATXYCB%3EABC11%3C%2F%20ATXYCB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBTCWZB%3EEFG22%3C%2FBTCWZB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%20CTATCB%3EIJK33%3C%2FCTATCB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%20DTCAAB%3ELMN44%3C%2FDTCAAB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20End%20T_C_B%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FT_C_B%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CD_C_B%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%20ADCB%3Exs%3Astring%3C%2F%20ADCB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%20BDCB%3Exs%3Astring%3C%2F%20BDCB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%20CDCB%3Exs%3Astring%3C%2F%20CDCB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20End%20D_%20C_B--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FD_C_B%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CU_C_B%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CUATXYCB%3EAA2B%3C%2F%20UATXYCB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBUTCWZB%3EBB4C%3C%2FBUTCWZB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%20UCTATCB%3EC8CD%3C%2FUCTATCB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%20DTUCAAB%3ED9DE%3C%2FDTUCAAB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20End%20U_C_B-%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FU_C_B%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FCode%3E)

C# Code:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"<\s*[UT]_C_B\s*>(?:\s*<\s*(?<name>[^<]*)>(?<val>[^<]*)<\s*/\s*\k<name>>.*?)+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var matchColl = rx.Matches(xml);
var result = string.Empty;
foreach (Match m in matchColl)
{ 
    for(int y = 0; y < m.Groups["name"].Captures.Count; y++)
        result += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? "" : "|") + 
             string.Format("{0}={1}", m.Groups["name"].Captures[y].Value, 
                                  m.Groups["val"].Captures[y].Value);
}
```

Both approaches result in:

[image]

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you 
(a tick on the left below the down arrow).

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML parse with XDocument:

```
string str = "";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = doc.Root.Elements();
foreach (XElement e in elements)
{
    if ((e.Name == "T_C_B") || (e.Name == "U_C_B"))
    {
         IEnumerable<XElement> nextElmt = e.Elements();
         foreach (XElement x in nextElmt)
         {
              str += string.Format("{0}={1}", x.Name, x.Value);
              str += "|";
         }
    }
}

str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

You can try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kOudWl

Comment: If the file contains the same errors as in the sample input, you will need pre-processing before parsing with `XDocument`.